# Explicit construction of Haar measure on a locally profinite group

Tags: measure-theory, topological-groups

Let $G$ be a [locally profinite group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_profinite_group).
A Haar measure $\mu$ on $G$ is a measure defined on the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal B(G)$ of all Borel sets of $G$ with the following properties.

> 1) $\mu(K) \lt \infty$ for every compact set $K$.
>
> 2) $\mu(U) = \text{sup} \{\mu(K) : K \subset U$, where $K$ is compact$\}$ for every open set $U$.
>
> 3) $\mu(E) = \text{inf} \{\mu(U): E \subset U$, where $U$ is open $\}$ for every $E\in \mathcal B(G)$.
>
> 4) $\mu(aE) = \mu(E)$ whenever $a\in G$ and $E\in \mathcal B(G)$.

My question is:

> Can we explicitly construct a Haar measure on $G$?

I am almost certain that we can explicitly construct a Haar mesure on $G$ if $G$ is compact, i.e. if $G$ is a profinite group.
I think the following threads are relevant to this problem.

[Explicit construction of Haar measure on a profinite group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1412088/explicit-construction-of-haar-measure-on-a-profinite-group)

[On formula $\sum_{i=1}^n 1/(G : H_i) = 1$ on a group $G$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1415162/on-formula-sum-i-1n-1-g-h-i-1-on-a-group-g)

[Construction of a Radon measure from a certain family of compact subsets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1294784/construction-of-a-radon-measure-from-a-certain-family-of-compact-subsets)